# Using Power View in SSRS

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2012, powerview

Is it required to have SharePoint server for working with Power View in SSRS? I have SQL Server with MSBI 2012. My client is inclined towards using Power view. Do I need need to install SharePoint (and pay for it) to  use Power view in SSRS with SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: PowerView's great, but I'd make sure you and your client know what you're getting before committing to buying anything.  PowerView is still very young, and has an extremely limited feature set when compared to SSRS.  As such, it's great for quick mock-ups and basic visualisation, but not something that's really all that suitable for large-scale reporting....yet.

Comment: Depends what you mean by large-scale. It can certainly report on large data sets, and its visualisations are far from basic. It just doesn't have some of the 'enterprise/standard' features we've come to expect from some of our more staid tools like SSRS, like exporting to PDF etc. If you consider easy self service BI or interactivity a feature set, it surpasses SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. From Microsoft:

> Power View is now a feature of Microsoft Excel 2013, and is part of
>   the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services add-in for Microsoft
>   **SharePoint Server** 2010 and 2013 Enterprise Editions.

And:

> Power View is a browser-based Silverlight application launched from
>   **SharePoint Server** 2010

More details:

[Power View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213579.aspx).

[System Requirements for Power View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560549.aspx).

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted that first quote. Power View is available in Microsoft Excel 2013, and also SharePoint... It can be used in Microsoft Excel w/o SharePoint. However only in Office Professional Plus.

Comment: That's true, but the question was in the context of Power View in SSRS; SharePoint is required in that situation. But fair point about being in Excel independent of both - it's useful information in the overall context here.